# how to have Swift <BACK seque tap cause a func on the parent view to execute?

Tags: ios, swift

When a user taps <BACK on my 2nd view and it re-opens the 1st view, how can I make software run on the 1st view?

<BACK triggers didDisappear but I think at that points it's too early to execute a func on the 1st view.  And of course 1st view's ViewDidLoad doesn't execute a 2nd time.

Comment: did u try viewWillAppear/didAppear on 1st view?

Answer (score 0):

Override viewWillAppear func in 1st view and put all the code of viewDidLoad into the viewWillAppear func.

It will excute the code of 1st view each
time when it appears.

And 1st view will refresh itself each time when back btn of 2nd view pressed.